# Can I still use the Ethernet ports on an ISP's modem after setting it to bridge mode?

Tags: networking, router, ethernet, bridge

So right now I have two network devices: A Huawei modem/router from my ISP, and an ASUS WiFi router that I bought separately. How I currently have it set up is the ASUS router is running on AP mode, so the Huawei modem/router is the one doing all the LAN stuff and handling the actual network. The ASUS router connects to the Huawei modem via ethernet, and it runs as a WiFi access point, so all my devices are connected to it (one desktop connected via ethernet, everything else on 2.4GHz/5GHz WiFi), **EXCEPT** for a second desktop that's connected directly to the Huawei device via ethernet.

Since the Huawei is handling the network there's no problem with this setup as all my devices are on the same network. This is fine except for the fact that I can't seem to configure QoS on this Huawei device, which is causing some issues with bandwidth allocation. My ASUS router is most likely a better device in all other aspects, too. My plan is to set the modem to bridge mode instead, and let the ASUS device handle the network. Shouldn't be a problem at all except for that one desktop connected directly to the Huawei device.

So my question is, if I set the Huawei router to bridge mode instead of router mode, would it act as a switch and let the desktop connect to the ASUS router? Or would I have to find a way to connect this desktop directly to the router?

Info I could find about the Huawei device: https://forum.huawei.com/enterprise/en/huawei-hg8145v5-an-informative-product-review/thread/763941-100181

Comment: It really depends on the ISP. In where I resides, one of the connection will break eventually, but it could be because I would be getting more than one public IPs in that case. If you are behind CGNAT after all, your ISP might not forbid it.

Comment: What kind of WAN connection do you have – fiber? cable/DOCSIS? 4G/LTE? ADSL?

Answer (score 1):

> So my question is, if I set the Huawei router to bridge mode instead of router mode, would it act as a switch

It already acts as a switch for the LAN ports; bridge mode would just add the WAN port to the whole thing, but usually without changing how the LAN ports behave.

(I believe 4G/LTE modems are an exception, however; they may *disable* all but one LAN port.)

> and let the desktop connect to the ASUS router? Or would I have to find a way to connect this desktop directly to the router?

In theory it would, yes, *but* the connection would be coming from the "WAN" side as far as the ASUS router knows. You'd have to specifically allow it through the router's firewall.

Also, depending on ISP, their systems might only issue *one* IP address lease per customer, so if the ASUS router boots up first, the desktop PC might not be able to obtain an IP address at all, or it might end up "stealing" the router's IP address. (This is especially the case for LTE/4G modems which I believe are architecturally limited to one IPv4, but may also apply to any kind of connection due to deliberate ISP restrictions.)

(And if it *does* get an IP address, your PC would be connected directly to the Internet – which is fine as long as you **never** disable the PC's built-in OS firewall, as there is no longer any other firewall blocking incoming connections.

If you're using the standard Windows firewall feature, it would need to remain set to "Public" (strictest) mode *all the time* and you would need to learn how to add precise exceptions via `wf.msc`, instead of just disabling the whole thing whenever something doesn't work.)

So overall I really would not recommend doing so. Get a longer Ethernet cable and move that desktop to the ASUS router instead. (Or if you prefer, get a PCI-Express Wi-Fi card.)

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest that any 'sensible' ISP router would remove all functionality except for one through port to your self-managed router. Anything else would just be asking for trouble from inexperienced users.

I can't say I have direct experience of every single ISP & router known to man, but every one I've had, from multiple ISPs, behaves this way. The port is often identified on the device - yellow printed square around the socket etc - or in the switchover instructions on its web interface.

Asking for it to also behave as a switch for the other sockets I don't think is a realistic expectation.
Consider it as a 'one trick gateway'. It will negotiate with your ISP [bear in mind many ISPs will only allow connection to one registered device, so this leave that device safely in play], then pass on a single DHCP gateway advertisement for your new router to sign onto.

Allowing multiple ports to still be active would mean you set up a race condition on power-up as to who gets to be the new gateway. Confusing experience for a consumer-oriented device.